# What's this "_function: while" syntax in Babel.js tail call?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Recently I'm looking at [Babel.js (previously 6to5)](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es6/#tail-calls). It's a transpiler for ES6. One interesting functionality it provides is to change tail calls to loops. In the example:

```
function factorial(n, acc = 1) {
    "use strict";
    if (n <= 1) return acc;
    return factorial(n - 1, n * acc);
}

// Stack overflow in most implementations today,
// but safe on arbitrary inputs in eS6
factorial(100000)
```

Babel.js transpile it to:

```
"use strict";

var _temporalAssertDefined = function (val, name, undef) { if (val === undef) { throw new ReferenceError(name + " is not defined - temporal dead zone"); } return true; };

var _temporalUndefined = {};
function factorial(_x2) {
    var _arguments = arguments;
    var _again = true;

    _function: while (_again) {
        var n = _temporalUndefined;
        var acc = _temporalUndefined;
        _again = false;
        var n = _x2;
        n = acc = undefined;
        n = _arguments[0] === undefined ? undefined : _arguments[0];
        acc = _arguments[1] === undefined ? 1 : _arguments[1];

        "use strict";
        if ((_temporalAssertDefined(n, "n", _temporalUndefined) && n) <= 1) {
            return _temporalAssertDefined(acc, "acc", _temporalUndefined) && acc;
        }_arguments = [_x2 = (_temporalAssertDefined(n, "n", _temporalUndefined) && n) - 1, (_temporalAssertDefined(n, "n", _temporalUndefined) && n) * (_temporalAssertDefined(acc, "acc", _temporalUndefined) && acc)];
        _again = true;
        continue _function;
    }
}

// Stack overflow in most implementations today,
// but safe on arbitrary inputs in eS6
factorial(100000);
```

My question is, I never saw a JavaScript syntax like `_function: while(again)`. But it's valid JavaScript! I tried to type simliar code like `a: 1` in Chrome devtools console and it's correct.

Could anyone tell me:

1. What's the name of this syntax?
2. Where can I get the syntax information?
3. In which case we need to write code like this?

Comment: In that statement, "_function" is a [**label**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.12).

Comment: Also, this is not a case where the label is useful. However, you really can't blame a dumb transpiler for not figuring that out.

Comment: bonus point for generating a topic digging ecma script. We need more of this little "research" side in SO!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a label and is used with continue, break:

```
my_label: while(true) {
  while(true) {
    break my_label;
  }
}
console.log('did we survive?');
```

> ### Avoid using labels
>
> Labels are not very commonly used in JavaScript since they make programs harder to read and understand. As much as possible, avoid using labels and, depending on the cases, prefer calling functions or throwing an error.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: meeh, all this label thing to avoid a few calls to `break`?  I don't buy it. +1 for pointing out to avoid it. Also, I have a feeling this kind of constructions is actually dirty shortcuts to bad coding habits. A bit like calling `return;` in the middle of a function instead of going through the flow covering all possible pathes...

Comment: Well in OP's code its a lot of mess to avoid capping the call stack - re factoring a recursive function call -> recursive iteration

Comment: It's not a "coding habit", it's just internal code generated by a tool; they can do whatever they want. No one is ever going to view or edit this code. It it works, that's fine.

Comment: @Sebas Some would consider using `break` in a loop bad practice. And no, it's not a trick to avoid a few calls to `break`. If you have multiple nested loops, breaking to the outer loop could be extremely convoluted and contrived if you don't use a label, whereas it's one simple line if you have a label.

Comment: @Sebas Consider this (how to archive the same without a label), then think about what is more clear: `while (true) { while(true) { break_outer=true; break; } if ( break_outer ) break; }`

Comment: @torazaburo I was discussing using labels in general.

Comment: @null To be fair, I'll tell you that I hear your point. As you can imagine, I equally faced these situations myself, and face them every day. With no arguing intention, I'd say I prefer two breaks that 1 call to a label. See, `break_outer` is meaningless and should not be named like that. If you use correct variable names (e.g. foundContract, foundContractLine...), the loops become very readable, and you don't take the risk to breaken away some essential functional pieces of code.